# PHP: Цикл foreach "сломался" и не перебирает массив)

Tags: php, массивы, циклы, foreach, данные

Рекурсией на каждом вызове функции наполнялся массив массивами, получилась такая группа массивов внутри одной переменной (результат вардампа):

```
array (
  12 => 
  array (
  ),
)
array (
  11 => 
  array (
    0 => '12',
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
  ),
)
array (
  3 => 
  array (
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => '11',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    0 => '13',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
  ),
)
array (
  1 => 
  array (
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '3',
    1 => '4',
    2 => '5',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    0 => '7',
    1 => '8',
    2 => '9',
    3 => '10',
  ),
)
```

Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь перебрать array(1), array(2), array(7) и тд, у меня ничего не выходит. Цикл foreach на 0-вой итерации показывает все массивы сразу, на первой итерации выводит:

```
array(1) {
  [12]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

на второй - опять все массивы.
Проверял так:

```
$i = 0;
        foreach($commonArr as $lk){
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($lk);
            echo '<pre>';
            $i++;
            if($i == 1) {
                exit;
            }
            }
```

Подскажите, как оптимизировать входящие в $commonArr массивы, чтобы можно было их обработать по одному?

**Как массив заполняется?**

```
 private function developCatalogue($objArr, $hierarchyArr, $allIds = [])
    {
        if(empty($allIds)) {
            $commonArr = [];
            foreach ($hierarchyArr as $item) {
                if($item[1] !== null) {
                    continue;
                }
                $allIds[$item[0]] = array();
            }
        }

        foreach ($allIds as $key => $id) {
            foreach ($hierarchyArr as $elem) {
                if ($elem[1] == $key) {
                    array_push($allIds[$key], $elem[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        $mergedArr = [];
        foreach($allIds as $arrArr) {
            $mergedArr = array_merge($mergedArr, $arrArr);
        }

        $mergedArr = array_flip($mergedArr);

        foreach($mergedArr as $obj => $content) {
            $mergedArr[$obj] = array();
        }

        $commonArr[] = $allIds;
        $allIds = $mergedArr;

        if(!empty($allIds)) {

            $this->developCatalogue($objArr, $hierarchyArr, $allIds);
        }
```

Comment: покажите, как вы его заполняете. И показыватть массив надо не картинкой, а текстом полученным 
 через `var_export($array);`

Comment: @splash58 приложил код, в результате которого сие получается в задачу (под всем остальным). Подзаголовок "Как массив заполняется?"

Comment: @splash58 заменил картинку на выдачу var_export()

Comment: первое, что вы можете сделать, это сделать одномерный массив из своего многомерного, это не сложно. Но очень похоже, что вы это же делаете в своей подпрограмме. Может, будет проще дать входные и желаемые выходные данные, а кто-то подскажет, как это сделать?

Comment: @splash58, к сожалению, не могу все подробности о задаче сообщить, пытаюсь создать дерево на основе таблицы, где есть 1-я колонка с номером объекта, 2-я с ее родителем, третья - с ребенком. С помощью рекурсии хочу получить все "разрезы" дерева в виде группы массивов, а затем, так как они последовательно к более глубокому идут, собрать их в одно дерево. Мне даже интересно в таком виде попробовать доделать. Хотел попросить помощи с локальной задачей перебора массива, который привел.. Представим, что ничего нет кроме него, он же все равно не будет правильно перебираться.. Правильно?

Comment: тогда показывайте структуру массива - сейчас это несколько массивов отдельно. как они связаны?

Comment: @splash58 я подумал, что это из-за отсутствия ключей.. сделал в строчке наполнения $commonArr вот так: $commonArr[$i+1] = $allIds; Но в итоге у меня все массивы, входящие в $commonArr приобретают ключ [1]

Comment: мне трудно без тестовых данных понять, где там что подкрутить. А массив давайте преобразуем. Только задачу правильно сформулируйте - вот, что есть, вот что надо

Comment: @splash58 Есть: массив (из задачи), в котором есть несколько подмассивов. Последний - это верхняя категория дерева. Второй от конца - новый срез. Это подкатегории предыдущего массива. Ниже - уже их подкатегории и тд. пока категории есть и работает рекурсия. Нужно, чтобы в цикле foreach можно было в каждой итерации обращаться к одному из массивов array(1) или array(2) или array(7). Так можно будет срезы склеить в общее дерево, зная, что каждый из них - потомки предыдущего..

Comment: splash58 извините, надеюсь, не запутал, объяснил как умею..

Comment: $commonArr = []; - вы его не используете. `$mergedArr = array_flip($allIds)` - зачем делать копию

Comment: а порядок важен?

Comment: @splash58 1. $commonArr = [] это объявление данного массива. Условие, в котором он объявляется, проходится только один раз - в начале, потому что $allIds пусто только в начале и в конце. 2. $mergedArr = array_flip($allIds) делаю ключами номера подкатегорий (а не значениями) и заменяю значения на пустые массивы, чтобы потом их наполнить, если и у данных подкатегорий есть свои вспомогательные элементы..

Comment: @splash58 хотел бы сохранить порядок, чувствую он может помочь, или перевернуть, чтобы конец был началом, потому что сейчас массив верхних категорий в конце, а при переборе лучше, чтобы верх был с начала, мне кажется..

Comment: вообще, мне кажется должно быть так: 0 показывает на вершину или вершины (массив индексов), а потом индекс элемента показывает на потомков, тогда это все легко восстановить

Comment: @splash58 Не уверен, что правильно вас понял.. Если правильно, то массив категорий, у которых нет предков, будет доступен по [0], массивы потомков 1 уровня - [1], 2-го - [3].. В принципе, да, я тоже так хотел сделать

Comment: именно так. но в такую структуру только из исходных данных можно строить. Просто смотрите, кто родитель, если нет ноль. и добавляете в массив arr[индекс_родителя][] = мой_индекс. Он сразу станет плоским